# Layout Question about an iPhone app that uses css, Jquery and JQtouch

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I'm learning how to build an iphone site using Johnathan Stark's O'Reilly Building iPhone Apps book. For the purposes of this question, you will be able to understand my problem by looking at it from the desktop at www.saudialberta.com . If you look at the home page, it has two panels, `Dates` and `About`. If you click on 'Dates,' it opens a new page with 6 days on it.

**Question:**  If you look at the html below, I'm trying to understand what allows the unordered list inside "Dates" to open on a new page, rather than just appear below "Dates" on the same page, and, for that matter, what allows the "p" element inside "About" to appear on a new page rather than just below the About div, as the html would suggest.

Notice that there's no styling id or class on the "p" element inside the "about" div.  Since "Dates" and "About" are both "toolbars" i'm guessing it's something in the toolbar css.  The book also uses jqtouch and jquery, but there's nothing in those files (that I can see) that manipulates these html elements.

**Toolbar CSS**

```
.toolbar {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(img/toolbar.png) #000000 repeat-x;
    position: relative;
}
.black-translucent .toolbar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.toolbar > h1 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10px;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 1px 0 0 -75px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 -1px 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kilo</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqtouch/jqtouch.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="themes/jqt/theme.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="kilo.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch/jqtouch.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="kilo.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="home">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Kilo</h1>
                <a class="button flip" href="#settings">Settings</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="edgetoedge">
                <li class="arrow"><a href="#dates">Dates</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Kilo gives you easy access to your food diary.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dates">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Dates</h1>
                <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="edgetoedge">
                <li class="arrow"><a id="0" href="#date">Today</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a id="1" href="#date">Yesterday</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a id="2" href="#date">2 Days Ago</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a id="3" href="#date">3 Days Ago</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a id="4" href="#date">4 Days Ago</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a id="5" href="#date">5 Days Ago</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="date">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Date</h1>
                <a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
                <a class="button slideup" href="#createEntry">+</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="edgetoedge">
                <li id="entryTemplate" class="entry" style="display:none">
                    <span class="label">Label</span>
                    <span class="calories">000</span>
                    <span class="delete">Delete</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="createEntry">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>New Entry</h1>
                <a class="button cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <ul class="rounded">
                    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Food" name="food" id="food" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Calories" name="calories" id="calories" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" /></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" class="submit" name="action" value="Save Entry" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="settings">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Settings</h1>
                <a class="button cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <ul class="rounded">
                    <li><input placeholder="Age" type="text" name="age" id="age" /></li>
                    <li><input placeholder="Weight" type="text" name="weight" id="weight" /></li>
                    <li><input placeholder="Budget" type="text" name="budget" id="budget" /></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" class="submit" name="action" value="Save Changes" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqtouch treats all top level divisions as pages. So because they are top level divisions, the javascript in jqtouch takes control of them, and styles them appropriately. Then converts links that match the id to reveal the pages.

Comment: thanks. In the html, there are other top level divisions (at least on the same level as the first two) that don't appear on the first page of my site- i.e. the div with the id "createEntry".  Can you think of a reason why createEntry's not on the first page? I did a multi-page search for that id, and it's not even being styled..

Comment: there is a link to about because the home division has an unordered list with class `edgetoedge` and an item with class `arrow`, that has a link with href `#about`. The link pointing to the id of the hidden page is what makes the magic happen.